# email current url on if else condition with no send button

Tags: php, forms, email

)
i want the smallest possible script to send current URL via email without a send button
but as a result of an if { } else {} condition..

ideas anyone?

ok.. i have gotten so far.. got a script on one end reciving and mailing
the desired data to the desired email.. then i need a way to send the current
page URL without a send button but as a result of an if (!notsomething) {} else{ send!!}

so i have this so far AND it works!! but i am getting partial URL
instead of "http://www.example.com/subfile.php" i am getting just "/subfile.php"

```
$websiteurl = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$curl_connection =  curl_init('http://www.sagive.co.il/downloads/wordpress/linkRemovedNotification.php');

//set options
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)");
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

//set data to be posted
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $websiteurl);

//perform our request
$result = curl_exec($curl_connection);

//show information regarding the request
print_r(curl_getinfo($curl_connection));
echo curl_errno($curl_connection) . '-' . curl_error($curl_connection);
//close the connection
curl_close($curl_connection);
```

**For some weird reason it wont send when i use:**

```
$websiteurl = $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
```

.
SO.. thats the last problem.. ideas anyone?

Comment: Smallest code? Try CodeGolf.SE ;)

Comment: Have you tried writing it yourself? Might get some answers if you give it a go, post your code, and ask if it can be optimized.

Comment: i have no clue as to how to write a "no send button form" .. thats why i am asking :) (why the minus??! WHY - is asking for help so bad!?!)

Comment: You could use cURL or a redirect with request params. Asking someone else to write your code for you probably got the downvote but not sure since I wasn't the one...

Comment: i dont need to get completed code.. just a pointer.. and example, a link.. something.. tried searching but getting unreleated results.. anyhow.. its ok i guess.. altough i have never done that -1 unless it was spam. - just hope someone would giveme a pointer

Comment: *"as a result of an if { } else {} condition"* - What does this mean? Why is this important to you? The minus is probably because your question is incomprehensible and fragmented. You're also asking for a complete solution having shown no effort.

Comment: as i have said before i need some help.. p.s - thanks for the pointer @jk - i have revised..

Comment: what's wrong with using mail() ?

Comment: its from one remote server to another.. almost got it - revised..

Comment: still can't grab the variable $websiteurl on the reciving end.. Help anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok! solved it :) - thanks for your help and your time.
here is the code i used and it works (Collected from sites across the web)

```
//extract data from the post
$currentw = $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
$currentth = SpaceJunkie;

//set POST variables
$url = 'http://www.example.com';
$fields = array(
                        'siteurl'=>urlencode($currentwebsite),
                        'themename'=>urlencode($currentheme),
                );

//url-ify the data for the POST
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string,'&');


//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: I still don't even know what the problem was.

Comment: I wanted to send an email the current email if check failed automatically. To top script didn’t work… my answer (After much research) works gr8. Hope I didn’t waste anyone time and that it would help anyone..

Answer (score 0):

Look into jQuery for this probably

```
<script rel="javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
   $.post('ajax/test.html?url='+window.location.pathname)
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for your help man.. since its from one server to another this (i think :) ) does not fit